# Bundle showing 'No visible options in feature' in Configure product screen - salesforce CPQ

Tags: cpq

I have mapped features to all the options in the bundle, Could anyone assist where i missed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add pricebook for those product which you are using in Product Option's (Object) field - Optional SKU then this error will be solved